# Passing commandline arguments to electron app

Tags: electron

I'm trying to create an electron application that interacts with files. Appart from the ability to drag files into the app I also want to add it to *sendTo* on windows and have an *OpenWith* entry for it. The later two boil down to windows explorer opening the electron app with the path(s) to the file(s) appended as commandline arguments.

Reading up on the topic it seems people just go with *process.argv* and process it through *yargs* or similar. The problem is I don't even receive the *real* arguments. My arguments look likes this:

```
"C:\\[...]\\app\\build\\win-unpacked\\app.exe",
"--type=renderer",
"--no-sandbox",
"--primordial-pipe-token=XXXX",
"--lang=de",
"--app-path=C:\\[..]\\app\\build\\win-unpacked\\resources\\app.asar",
"--node-integration=true",
"--webview-tag=true",
"--no-sandbox",
"--enable-pinch",
"--device-scale-factor=1",
"--num-raster-threads=4",
"--enable-main-frame-before-activation",
"--content-image-texture-target=[...]
"--service-request-channel-token=xxxx",
"--renderer-client-id=4",
"--mojo-platform-channel-handle=xxx",
"/prefetch:1"
```

If I start the packaged app

```
app.exe "123" "456"
```

There is no change in the arguments. Looking at the process in process-explorer:

```
app.exe (The proper arguments i.e. "123" "456")
 +-> app.exe (The messy arguments described above)
 +-> app.exe (The messy arguments described above)
```

How do I patch through the arguments of the exe-wrapper to my actual application?
I looked at pre-existing answers but they boil down to *use argv* or start the *electron.exe* differently. I'm using argv already and I don't call *electron.exe*.

I'm using the electron-vue template.

The output of electron-builder:

```
electron-builder 19.24.1
No native production dependencies
Packaging for win32 x64 using electron 1.7.5 to build\win-unpacked
Building NSIS installer
  Packaging NSIS installer for arch x64
```

It all seems fine. Am I missing something here?